# How to replace this componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a login and register component with forms that were created a while ago before these methods were deprecated, I've been looking around but cannot seem to find a solution, how would I go about refactoring this to using `getDerivedStateFromProps`?

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.auth.isAuthenticated) {
      this.props.history.push("/dashboard")
    }

    if (nextProps.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: nextProps.errors
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question you *asked* is probably not going to be satisfactory. :-) The answer is that **if** you really need to derive state from props ([you probably don't](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state), just use `props.errors` directly in `render`), you do it with the newer [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) `static` method that accepts props and state and (potentially) returns a state update to apply:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return props.errors ? {errors: props.errors} : null;
}
```

or with destructuring and without the unused `state` parameter:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(({errors})) {
    return errors ? {errors} : null;
}
```

***But***, you're saying "But that doesn't do the authentication thing...?" That's right, it doesn't, because that `componentWillReceiveProps` shouldn't have, either, it violates the rule [`props` are read-only](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props-are-read-only). So that part shouldn't be there. Instead, if that entry in `props.history` is supposed to be there, it should be put there by the parent component.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `componentWillReceiveProps` to keep a local state in sync with `props` you have two alternatives:

Declare your initial state based on props and use `componentDidUpdate` to ensure props synchronicity

```
class Component extends React.Component{
    state = { foo : this.props.foo }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        if(this.props.foo !== prevProps.foo)
            this.setState({ foo : prevProps.foo })
    }
}
```

This is actually triggering an extra render everytime, if you have some local state that is always equal to some prop you can use the prop directly instead.

Use `getDerivedStateFromProps` to update the state based on a prop change, but keep in mind that [you probably don't need to use it](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state)

```
class Component extends React.Component{
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props){
        return { foo : props.foo }
    }
}
```